# How run a command, show stderr on screen, and at the same time, save stderr in a file

Tags: bash, stderr, io-redirection

I want to run a command, show stderr on screen and, at the same time, save stderr in a file.

Answer (score 1):

In bash (or zsh), you can do this by redirecting stderr to `tee` via a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
somecommand 2> >(tee errors.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

This command shows stdout and stderr on screen and saves stderr on /tmp/errors:

```
$ ( ls file_do_not_exist /bin/true 2>&1 1>&3 | tee /tmp/errors 1>&2; ) 3>&1
```